# What is the difference between shouldComponentUpdate and componentWillUpdate in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a doubt , when we are using react component methods there are methods with same behavior, and also they are called one by one in the component life cycle ? then what is the major difference,

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
  // It will be executed with nextProps and nextState
} 
componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
  // It will be executed first with same data nextProps, nextState
}
```

In the above example We have same parameter data with same behavior but the shouldComponentUpdate will be called first.

**Then what is the main difference ?**

Comment: Read the docs. It's clearly explained there.

Comment: Your snippet uses in both cases the same method.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP didn't spend time reading the official documentation

Comment: > Use shouldComponentUpdate() to let React know if a component's output is not affected by the current change in state or props. The default behavior is to re-render on every state change, and in the vast majority of cases you should rely on the default behavior.

Comment: > componentWillUpdate() is invoked immediately before rendering when new props or state are being received. Use this as an opportunity to perform preparation before an update occurs. This method is not called for the initial render.

Comment: ALL in the docs

Comment: @taha Why are you writing an answer as a series of comments?

Comment: @TomFenech it's not an answer I'm proud of. all taken from the docs

Comment: In that case, you could make it a community wiki answer, or just post a link to the docs in the comments (or ignore me entirely and do what you want :^)

Comment: Thanks for all the minus votes ... It needs some deep research why we have this methods

Answer (score 13):

The function ***ComponentWillUpdate*** will be executed, if function ***shouldComponentUpdate*** returns true.

If ***shouldComponentUpdate*** returns false, then ***ComponentWillUpdate*** will not be called.

Here is document of 2 functions : [componentwillupdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillupdate) and [shouldcomponentupdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate).

You can read here [component-lifecycle](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle)

I hope it's helpful to you.

Comment: So you can return false from shouldComponentUpdate, but you can't from ComponentWillUpdate. The second Seems pointless. React thinks so too, as they deprecated ComponentWillUpdate.